# Is there a way to use Python to access IPhone camera resolution?

Tags: iphone, python-3.x, resolution, ios-camera

I know you can use objective-c to access it, but wondering is there any Python module that let us do the same thing?

Comment: What are you using to make an iOS app with python?

Comment: I am using kivy

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [pythonista](/questions/tagged/pythonista) app on your [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), there is [photos](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/photos.html#module-photos) library.
※ You can browse other libraries [here](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/).

[Photos](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/photos.html#module-photos) library can provide you such API as

1. [capture_image(camera='rear')](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/photos.html#photos.capture_image)
2. [get_metadata(image_index=-1)](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/photos.html#deprecated-functions)
   ※ Unfortunately, there is no info about resolution. At least I didn't find.
3. and so on

But it doesn't provide you direct access to camera resolution.